# Background image not covering on viewport size change on iPhones

Tags: jquery, css

I am building an JQuery app with a background image. I used these styles to ensure the image stays centered:

```
body {
-webkit-background-size: cover; 
-moz-background-size: cover; 
-o-background-size: cover; 
background-size: cover;
background: url('storm2.jpg') no-repeat center fixed;
padding-bottom: 100px; 
}
```

This works for most pages. However, I have a page that changes sizes after the initial load. The app provides users the ability to toggle more data into the view. When the toggle is used on an iPhone, large white blocks appears in the background image. The image seems unable to handle the changing size of the viewport. I'm a bit stumped about how to fix this specific issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you provide a screen shot? or may the measurements of the image and/or the screens your testing on? (or even what iPhone)

Comment: You could try refreshing the css rule after the initial load  $('body').css("background", "url('storm2.jpg') no-repeat center fixed");

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with the viewport changing size but elements changing size. This question has been asked before and there's almost no way we can help you here without an example of it being broken